# Replicate the format of a video to another

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, codec, avi

Let's say I have:

- `video1.avi` which is perfectly played (both sound and image) on my TV's USB media input
- `video2.avi` which is not recognized by the TV: "Imposible to read this format"

I have tried lots of solutions, like:

```
ffmpeg -i video2.avi -codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 0 -ac 2 -ar 48000 -joint_stereo 0^
       -codec:v libxvid -q:v 25 video2_reencoded.avi
```

and when I compare `video1.avi` with `video2_reencoded.avi` with [MediaInfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaInfo), they look similar in most aspects, **but finally the TV won't play `video2_reencoded.avi`**.

**Is there a way with `ffmpeg`, to replicate all the specifications of `video1.avi` (sound encoding properties, video encoding properties, image size, container type, etc.) on `video2.avi`?**

---

**Appendix**: output of MediaInfo for the three videos. In this specific example, `video2.avi` and `video2_reencoded.avi` are half-working: image ok but not the sound. In other video examples I tried, `video2.avi` and `video2_reencoded.avi` would be both totally "Impossible to read".

`video1.avi` (i.e. working)

```
Format                                   : AVI
Format/Info                              : Audio Video Interleave
File size                                : 352 MiB
Duration                                 : 51 min 22 s
Overall bit rate                         : 959 kb/s
Writing application                      : VirtualDubMod 1.5.10.3 | ... || (build 2550/release)
Writing library                          : VirtualDubMod build 2550/release

Video
ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : MPEG-4 Visual
Format profile                           : Advanced Simple@L5
Format settings                          : BVOP1
Format settings, BVOP                    : 1
Format settings, QPel                    : No
Format settings, GMC                     : No warppoints
Format settings, Matrix                  : Default (MPEG)
Codec ID                                 : XVID
Codec ID/Hint                            : XviD
Duration                                 : 51 min 22 s
Bit rate                                 : 821 kb/s
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 400 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.114
Stream size                              : 302 MiB (86%)
Writing library                          : XviD 1.2.1 (UTC 2008-12-04)

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Codec ID                                 : 55
Codec ID/Hint                            : MP3
Duration                                 : 51 min 22 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 47.0 MiB (13%)
Alignment                                : Aligned on interleaves
Interleave, duration                     : 40  ms (1.00 video frame)
Interleave, preload duration             : 504  ms
Writing library                          : LAME3.99r
Encoding settings                        : -m s -V 4 -q 2 -lowpass 17 -b 128
```

`video2.avi` (i.e. non-working)

```
Format                                   : AVI
Format/Info                              : Audio Video Interleave
File size                                : 1.37 GiB
Duration                                 : 2 h 12 min
Overall bit rate                         : 1 478 kb/s
Writing application                      : VirtualDubMod 1.5.10.2 Fr | ... ||  (build 2540/release)
Writing library                          : VirtualDubMod build 2540/release

Video
ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : MPEG-4 Visual
Format profile                           : Advanced Simple@L5
Format settings                          : BVOP1
Format settings, BVOP                    : 1
Format settings, QPel                    : No
Format settings, GMC                     : No warppoints
Format settings, Matrix                  : Default (H.263)
Muxing mode                              : Packed bitstream
Codec ID                                 : XVID
Codec ID/Hint                            : XviD
Duration                                 : 2 h 12 min
Bit rate                                 : 1 084 kb/s
Width                                    : 624 pixels
Height                                   : 368 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 5:3
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.189
Stream size                              : 1.00 GiB (73%)
Writing library                          : XviD 1.2.1 (UTC 2008-12-04)

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AC-3
Format/Info                              : Audio Coding 3
Codec ID                                 : 2000
Duration                                 : 2 h 12 min
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 384 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 6 channels
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 364 MiB (26%)
Alignment                                : Split accross interleaves
Interleave, duration                     : 40  ms (1.00 video frame)
Interleave, preload duration             : 512  ms
```

`video2_reencoded.avi` (i.e. non-working, reencoded, but still non-working)

```
Format                                   : AVI
Format/Info                              : Audio Video Interleave
Format profile                           : OpenDML
File size                                : 1.13 GiB
Duration                                 : 2 h 12 min
Overall bit rate                         : 1 227 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf57.26.100

Video
ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : MPEG-4 Visual
Format profile                           : Advanced Simple@L5
Format settings                          : BVOP1
Format settings, BVOP                    : 1
Format settings, QPel                    : No
Format settings, GMC                     : No warppoints
Format settings, Matrix                  : Default (H.263)
Muxing mode                              : Packed bitstream
Codec ID                                 : XVID
Codec ID/Hint                            : XviD
Duration                                 : 2 h 12 min
Bit rate                                 : 1 084 kb/s
Width                                    : 624 pixels
Height                                   : 368 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 5:3
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.189
Stream size                              : 1.00 GiB (88%)
Writing library                          : XviD 1.2.1 (UTC 2008-12-04)

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Codec ID                                 : 55
Codec ID/Hint                            : MP3
Duration                                 : 2 h 12 min
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 120 MiB (10%)
Alignment                                : Aligned on interleaves
Interleave, duration                     : 24  ms (0.60 video frame)
```

Comment: @LordNeckbeard a screenshot of the MediaInfo GUI or another way?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard:  I copied/pasted video1.avi, video2.avi and video2_reencoded.avi.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but unfortunately there is no such tool available. Currently the best you can get in this direction is the replication of h264 encoding parameters.

Comment: The way i know is to read the advanced output of mediainfo and copy them into a manually created preset like described here [link](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/19571/openload-cc-how-can-i-extract-encoding-settings-of-videos/19577)

Comment: It seems that my videos are not h264, right @Harry?

Comment: In your mediainfos i see that "Format settings, Matrix " is the only noticeable difference between 1 and 3. Did you try to set -mpeg_quant 1 in order to force MPEG instead of h263 quantisation? Also i see your test output is 1GB, did you know you can stop ffmpeg encoding by CTRL+C and you still get a correct file but just shorter? ;-)

Comment: @Basj, well XVID is kind of h264, maybe your decoder has better support for the libx264 codec ;-)

Comment: In fact for this very specific video, the image is working (the TV reads the video) but no sound is played ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156392/discussion-between-harry-and-basj).

Comment: Xvid is not kind of  H264 - they are different codecs.